# SpatiaLite database error: no such table, but it is present in the SpatiaLite database

Tags: qgis, sql, attribute-joins

I am new to databases in QGIS, but cannot find any answer in all the documentation and online help in a weeks worth of desperate searching.  I think this might be a newbie error, but just cannot solve this issue.

I am trying to join two attribute tables from two point shapefiles [j_pipeline_inc (multipoint) to the j_pipeline_midpts (point)] using a SQL expression (image attached):

```
SELECT j_pipeline_midpts.*, j_pipeline_inc.*
FROM j_pipeline_midpts
INNER JOIN j_pipeline_midpts
on j_pipeline_midpts.LSD = j_pipeline_inc.LOCATION and j_pipeline_midpts.Licence_No=j_pipeline_inc.LICENCE_NO
```

The join will be based on two keys (LSD & Location, Licence_No & LICENCE_NO).  I have created a SpatiaLite database (incident_move.sqlite), which has these two point shapefiles in it, but when I execute my expression it states: "no such table: j_pipeline_inc".  I don't understand why it doesn't recognize one of the files.  When I type their names in the expression box it shows both shapefile names in the autocomplete.

I have tried saving one file as a SpatiaLite file type then importing the other to that database, but it still gives me the same error.

Also, they both have the same projection (EPSG:3400 - NAD83).

[image: view of my SQL expression and SpatiaLite database]

Comment: [dba.se] is a better fit for pure SQL questions.

Comment: `I have created a SpatiaLite database (incident_move.sqlite), which has these two point shapefiles in it,` if the data from the shapefiles is in  a spatialite database, they are no longer shapefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple mistake in the table name. Change the table name to *j_pipeline_inc* after INNER JOIN. Try this:

```
SELECT j_pipeline_midpts.*, j_pipeline_inc.*
FROM j_pipeline_midpts
INNER JOIN j_pipeline_inc
on j_pipeline_midpts.LSD = j_pipeline_inc.LOCATION and
j_pipeline_midpts.Licence_No=j_pipeline_inc.LICENCE_NO
```

Comment: Thank you.  What a simple fix.  SQL is a very powerful tool, but I am new and make these little mistakes that cause sych frustration.